# `__init__` called twice?

Tags: python

Here is a simplified Python code:

```
class Base:
    __possible_types__ = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> type:
        # pop the `__type__` argument because it
        # should be passed to the class `__init__`
        type_ = kwargs.pop("__type__", None)

        if type_ is not None:
            possible_type = cls.__possible_types__.get(type_)

            if possible_type is not None:
                return possible_type(*args, **kwargs)
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.__init__", args, kwargs)

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        __possible_types__ = {}

        for parent in cls.__mro__[1:]:
            if issubclass(parent, Base):
                parent.__possible_types__[cls.__name__] = cls


class Parent(Base):
    pass


class Child(Parent):
    pass 


class Adult(Parent):
    pass


should_be_child = Parent(
    name="bob",
    __type__="Child"
)

print(should_be_child)
```

and here is the output:

```
Child.__init__ () {'name': 'bob'}
Child.__init__ () {'name': 'bob', '__type__': 'Child'}
<__main__.Child object at 0x...>
```

A few questions

- Why is `__init__` called twice?
- How is the popped dict item (`__type__`) back in the second `__init__` call?
- How do I solve this?

Comment: Try adding print statements to all the functions.

Comment: Use your debugger! Step through the code line-by-line.

Comment: The docs are helpful here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

Comment: A new object is created here: `return possible_type(*args, **kwargs)` and that involves `__init__`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see the point of using `for parent in cls.__mro__[1:]:` and then adding `parent.__possible_types__[cls.__name__] = cls`... this has ultimately the same effect as `Base.__possible_types__[cls.__name__] = cls` just in a much less convoluted way

Comment: @Mark and an understanding of what `type.__call__` does, which is essentially what's going on here, as far as I can tell, since `type.__call__` is used twice, the object gets `__init__`ed twice

Comment: As an aside, this is **why you shouldn't abuse `__new__` this way to achieve what a simple factory function would**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem. Two distinct calls.

Two disctinct calls for `Child` are made. One as result of the call to `Parent()`, and the other when you call `possible_type(*args, **kwargs)` *inside* `Base`'s constructor.

As `possible_type` *e.g.* `Child` does not override `__new__`, it inherits the first one available from its parents. That ultimately means that `Parent( ..., __type__ = ...)` calls to construct a `Child` in the process as `Child` is a subclass of `Parent`, `possible_type(*args, **kwargs)` gets called, which in turn calls `__new__` with no subclasses of it's own and thus it does so failling the check, and calls yet again `super`'s `__new__`.

This is the reason with two *distinct* `__init__` calls get made, and why it *appears to be* that `__new__` is "leaking" the popped dict item `__type__`.
When actually, it's only being passed to its parent's constructor but not `Child`'s

This is made clear with some strategically put "debugging" `print()`s

```py
class Base:
    __possible_types__ = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> type:
        # pop the `__type__` argument because it
        # should be passed to the class `__init__`
        type_ = kwargs.pop("__type__", None)

        if type_ is not None:
            possible_type = cls.__possible_types__.get(type_)

            if possible_type is not None:
                return possible_type(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"\n__new__ called {cls=}\n")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.__init__", args, kwargs)

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        __possible_types__ = {}
        print(f"\n__init_subclass__ called {cls}")

        for parent in cls.__mro__[1:]:
            if issubclass(parent, Base):
                print(f"{parent=}")
                parent.__possible_types__[cls.__name__] = cls


class Parent(Base):
    pass


class Child(Parent):
    pass 


class Adult(Parent):
    pass


should_be_child = Parent(
    name="bob",
    __type__="Child"
)
print(should_be_child)

should_be_adult = Parent(
    name="lisa",
    __type__="Adult"
)
print(should_be_adult)

should_be_just_parent = Parent(
    name="mark",
    __type__ = "isNotASubclass"
)

print(should_be_just_parent)
```

Output:

```py
__init_subclass__ called <class '__main__.Parent'>
parent=<class '__main__.Base'>

__init_subclass__ called <class '__main__.Child'>
parent=<class '__main__.Parent'>
parent=<class '__main__.Base'>

__init_subclass__ called <class '__main__.Adult'>
parent=<class '__main__.Parent'>
parent=<class '__main__.Base'>

__new__ called cls=<class '__main__.Child'>

Child.__init__ () {'name': 'bob'}
Child.__init__ () {'name': 'bob', '__type__': 'Child'}
<__main__.Child object at 0x000001CFC783EED0>

__new__ called cls=<class '__main__.Adult'>

Adult.__init__ () {'name': 'lisa'}
Adult.__init__ () {'name': 'lisa', '__type__': 'Adult'}
<__main__.Adult object at 0x000001CFC783EF10>

__new__ called cls=<class '__main__.Parent'>

Parent.__init__ () {'name': 'mark', '__type__': 'isNotASubclass'}
<__main__.Parent object at 0x000001CFC783EE90>
```

As you see, it is `Parent`s `__init__` that's being called with `__type__`. And in the example I've given avobe, the code reaches `print(f"\n__new__ called {cls=}\n")` in very case, despite a subclass being detected and a new instance of that class being constructed.

### Quick-fix. A one-line edit.

You can solve this by only making the call in the case that `possible_types is None == True`.

```py
class Base:
    __possible_types__ = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> type:
        # pop the `__type__` argument because it
        # should be passed to the class `__init__`
        type_ = kwargs.pop("__type__", None)

        if type_ is not None:
            possible_type = cls.__possible_types__.get(type_)

            if possible_type is not None:
                return super().__new__(possible_type) # Modified line
        print(f"\n__new__ called {cls=}\n")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.__init__", args, kwargs)

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        __possible_types__ = {}
        print(f"\n__init_subclass__ called {cls}")

        for parent in cls.__mro__[1:]:
            if issubclass(parent, Base):
                print(f"{parent=}")
                parent.__possible_types__[cls.__name__] = cls


class Parent(Base):
    pass


class Child(Parent):
    pass 


class Adult(Parent):
    pass


should_be_child = Parent(
    name="bob",
    __type__="Child"
)
print(should_be_child)

should_be_adult = Parent(
    name="lisa",
    __type__="Adult"
)
print(should_be_adult)

should_be_just_parent = Parent(
    name="mark",
    __type__ = "isNotASubclass"
)

print(should_be_just_parent)
```

Output:

```py
__init_subclass__ called <class '__main__.Parent'>
parent=<class '__main__.Base'>

__init_subclass__ called <class '__main__.Child'>
parent=<class '__main__.Parent'>
parent=<class '__main__.Base'>

__init_subclass__ called <class '__main__.Adult'>
parent=<class '__main__.Parent'>
parent=<class '__main__.Base'>
Child.__init__ () {'name': 'bob', '__type__': 'Child'}
<__main__.Child object at 0x000002806AE4EF10>
Adult.__init__ () {'name': 'lisa', '__type__': 'Adult'}
<__main__.Adult object at 0x000002806AE4EE90>

__new__ called cls=<class '__main__.Parent'>

Parent.__init__ () {'name': 'mark', '__type__': 'isNotASubclass'}
<__main__.Parent object at 0x000002806AE4EED0>
```

In this modified version only call gets made in every case, and the code only reaches `print(f"\n__new__ called {cls=}\n")` when no subclasses where found.
Regarding further clarifications in [juanpa.arivillaga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77224870/22049099) indeed
'hijackin' `__new__` to make a factory patern is very error-prone, and could be simplified by insted implementing that pattern with a static or class method.

### A more "sound" solution. Implementing a factory pattern via a classmethod.

```py
class Base:
    __possible_types__ = {}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.__init__", args, kwargs)
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        __possible_types__ = {}

        Base.__possible_types__[cls.__name__] = cls


    @classmethod
    def create_base(cls, *args, __type__, **kwargs):
        return cls.__possible_types__[__type__](*args, **kwargs)

class Parent(Base):
    pass


class Child(Parent):
    pass


class Adult(Parent):
    pass

should_be_child = Base.create_base(
    name="bob",
    __type__="Child"
)
print(should_be_child)

should_be_adult = Base.create_base(
    name="lisa",
    __type__="Adult"
)
print(should_be_adult)
```

Output:

```py
Child.__init__ () {'name': 'bob'}
<__main__.Child object at 0x0000020FB123ECD0>
Adult.__init__ () {'name': 'lisa'}
<__main__.Adult object at 0x0000020FB11A4ED0>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see the point of using `for parent in cls.__mro__[1:]:` and then adding `parent.__possible_types__[cls.__name__] = cls`... this has ultimately the same effect as `Base.__possible_types__[cls.__name__] = cls` just in a much less convoluted way

Comment: I'm pretty sure only one object is being instantiated, just that `__init__` is called multiple times on it

Comment: The explanation of this answer doesn't look right

Comment: @dROOOze well, they are correct as for *why* `__init__` is called twice, I'm pretty sure, but only one object is created

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think so - `__init__` is definitely called twice on `child`. The op claimed that it isn't.

Comment: @dROOOze Basically, the issue is that two different invocations of `type.__call__` are used during the construction of the object, but only one object is constructted. the solution to use `return super().__new__(possible_type) # Modified line` is correct though

Comment: `possible_type` *e.g.* `Child` does not override `__new__` so it inherits the first one available from its parents. Correct me if i'm worng (and i be glad to edit the answer), but  that ultimately means that `Parent( ..., __type__ = ...)` when constructed, calls to construct a `Child`, which in turn calls `__new__` with no subclasses of it's own and thus failling the check thus calling yet again super's `__new__` That's why all cases reach the end print statement.

Comment: But **only one object is created**, which is the one that results from `return super().__new__(cls)` in the second pass through `Base.__new__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the clarification, i'll further trace back the construction and edit the answer.

Comment: in deed printing the id() of both calls gives the same number. Thanks!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've edited the post to give a more precise and correct explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, the issue *is* correctly identified in HernanATN's answer, which is that that you do:

```
return possible_type(*args, **kwargs)
```

But that doesn't mean that two objects get created. If we add this to `__init__`:

```
self.initialized = getattr(self, "initialized", 0) + 1
```

Then:

```
should_be_child = Parent(
    name="bob",
    __type__="Child"
)
print(should_be_child.initialized)
```

outputs:

```
2
```

The issue here is that you are relying on `type.__call__`, e.g. `SomeType(foo)` invokes the metaclass `__call__` which is what is responsible for coordinating `__new__` and `__init__`.  Both invocations end up invoking `__init__` on the *same instance* that is ultimately created in:

```
return super().__new__(cls)
```

But ultimately, the issue here is that you are using the class machinery to essentially have a factory pattern. You should just have a *function* which does this. It can even be called `Base`.

Here is a much more sane way to approach this in general:

```
class Base:
    possible_types = {}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.__init__", args, kwargs)

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        Base.possible_types[cls.__name__] = cls

def create_base(*args, type_, **kwargs):
    return Base.possible_types[type_](*args, **kwargs)

class Parent(Base):
    pass


class Child(Parent):
    pass


class Adult(Parent):
    pass


should_be_child = create_base(type_="Child")
```

Comment: Thanks for the more apropiate explanation!

Comment: this has nothing to do with `type.__call__`, according to the documentation "If __new__() is invoked during object construction and it returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s __init__() method will be invoked ...", I my case created & initialized my class here `return possible_type(*args, **kwargs)` in  `__new__`, which returned an instance, and python automatically called `__init__` again because I returned an instance, this also explains how my popped dict item came back

Comment: @dsal3389 *of course it has to do with `type.__call__`*, **where do you think the logic of** "if `__new__()` is invoked during object construction and it returns an instance of cls, then the new instances `__init__()` method will be invoked..." is contained? That happens *in [`type.__call__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/77e9aae3837d9f0cf87461d023896f2c4aeb282f/Objects/typeobject.c#L1646)*.

Comment: @dsal3389 do you understand that `possible_type(*args, **kwargs)` invoked `type.__call__`? `possible_type` is an instance of `type`, and you are using the call operator, i.e. `possible_type(...)`,  so it invokes `type.__call__`....

Comment: @juanpa-arrivillaga ahhhh yes I see it now

Answer (score 2):

It pays to understand what goes on when you create an instance using the syntax `Parent(name="bob", __type__="Child")`. First, note that the declaration

```py
class A: ...
```

is syntactic sugar for the following:

```py
class A(metaclass=type): ...
```

where `type` roughly looks like this, if it were implemented in Python:

```py
class type:
   ...
   def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
       self = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
       if isinstance(self, cls):
           self.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       return self
```

> Use the following implementation to step through with a debugger:
>
> ```py
> class type_(type):
>     def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
>         self = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
>         if isinstance(self, cls):
>             self.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>         return self
>
> class Base(metaclass=type_): ...
> ```

The [`__call__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-callable-objects) on `type` allows the syntax `A(<...>)` for creating an object.

---

Now, you can follow the code when you invoke `should_be_child = Parent(name="bob", __type__="Child")`. Basically, `type.__call__` is invoked twice, resulting in `Base.__new__` and `Child.__init__` to be both invoked twice. Your `"__type__": "Child"` is popped in `Base.__new__`, not `type.__call__`, because you've unpacked `**kwargs` inside `type.__call__` when you did `cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    kwargs.pop("asdf")
    print(kwargs, "inside f")

>>> asdf = {"asdf": None}
>>> f(**asdf)
{} inside f
>>> print(asdf, "outside f")
{"asdf": None} outside f
```